# deleting row a given row index after sorting c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, dataset

I build up my datagrid with bindnig source:

```
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Datenbank.cmd);
    dataSet1.Tables.Clear();
    adapter.Fill(dataSet1, "Table");
    bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = dataSet1.Tables["Table"];
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Now I sort grid

```
    bs.Sort = "customer DESC";
```

Now I want to remove row 0

```
    dataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.RemoveAt(0);
```

However, the row which was at position 0 before sorting will be deleted, not the row which now is on position 0

**//EDIT :**  is there similar for `test.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);` ?

Comment: Sorting with a binding source doesn't sort your original data table, it sorts a copy of it. You're better off using the data key rather than the row index to delete.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll could you please explain in more detail how to use data key rather than row index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not just remove it using the binding source 
e.g.

```
  bs.RemoveAt(0)
```

Regarding `test.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);`

`BindingSource.Insert(int, object)` or `BindingSource.List.Insert(int, object)` looks good but it isn't supported when the source is a DataSet.

This is because BindingSource.Insert just calls the `System.Collections.IList.Insert()` on the underlying list. The underlying list is a DataView. The implementation of Insert on Dataview is

```
private void System.Collections.IList.Insert(int index, object value)
{
    throw ExceptionBuilder.InsertExternalObject();
}
```

You can show this by

```
 System.Data.DataView dv = bs.List as DataView;
 System.Collections.IList list = dv;
 list.Insert(0,newRow); //BANG InsertExternalObject exception
```

Comment: is there similar for `test.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);` ?

Comment: [BindingSouce.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.insert.aspx) takes an integer and an object so yes, but I haven't tested

Comment: it says External objects can not be added to this list

Comment: Yeah I just looked into it. Updated my answer

Comment: yeah right this will throw an exception, but have you got any idea how to put a row into specific position after sorting? ive started new question, maybe you can refer there -> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336157/how-to-add-a-row-in-bindingsource-on-given-position-after-sorting-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

remove at binding source, not at dataset