# How to add a row in bindingsource on given position after sorting? C#

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I build up my datagrid with binding source:

```
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Datenbank.cmd);
    dataSet1.Tables.Clear();
    adapter.Fill(dataSet1, "Table");
    bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = dataSet1.Tables["Table"];
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Now i sort it:

```
    bs.Sort = "customer DESC";
```

Now I want to add new row at 0

```
    dataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);
```

However, it will not be insert at position 0

Similar problem with deleting at position x - which was solved in here
[>> stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335282/deleting-row-a-given-row-index-after-sorting-c-sharp)

thought of using `bs.insert(0,newRow)` but it says external objects can not be added to this list

**How to add a row in bindingsource on given position after sorting?**

Comment: I don't think there's a direct way to do it. The only think I can think of is to add a column and then populate it so that sorting worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works for adding to the top of the list - I have no idea if it is the best solution but it works. There are lots of other ways to approach the issue, including things like making your own binding collection that allows inserting into a sorted list, that could give *better* code form certain points of view, but this is simple at least.

Here is the code, which includes creating a datatable.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingSource bs;
    DataTable dt;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dt = new DataTable("Customers");
        DataColumn dc;

        dc = new DataColumn();
        dc.DataType = typeof(int);
        dc.ColumnName = "CustomerID";

        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("LastName"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirstName"));
        // Concatenation of first and last names 
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FullName"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Address"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("City"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("State"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Zip"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Phone"));

        dc = new DataColumn();
        dc.DataType = typeof(DateTime);
        dc.ColumnName = "LastPurchaseDate";
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);

        dc = new DataColumn();
        dc.DataType = typeof(int);
        dc.ColumnName = "CustomerType";
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        dt.Columns.Add("HiddenSort", typeof(bool));

        // Populate the table 
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "Baggins", "Bilbo", "Baggins, Bilbo", "Bagshot Row #1", "Hobbiton", "SH", "00001", "555-2222", DateTime.Parse("9/9/2008"), 1, false);
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "Baggins", "Frodo", "Baggins, Frodo", "Bagshot Row #2", "Hobbiton", "SH", "00001", "555-1111", DateTime.Parse("9/9/2008"), 1, false);
        dt.Rows.Add(6, "Bolger", "Fatty", "Bolger, Fatty", "ProudFeet Creek", "Hobbiton", "SH", "00001", "555-1111", DateTime.Parse("9/9/2008"), 1); dt.Rows.Add(4, "Elessar", "Aragorn", "Elessar, Aragorn", "Citadel", "Minas Tirith", "Gondor", "00000", "555-0000", DateTime.Parse("9/9/2008"), 4, false);
        dt.Rows.Add(5, "Evenstar", "Arwin", "Evenstar, Arwin", "Citadel", "Minas Tirith", "Gondor", "00000", "555-0001", DateTime.Parse("9/9/2008"), 4, false);
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "Greyhame", "Gandalf", "Grayhame, Gandalf", DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value, 3, false);

        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dt;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        dataGridView1.Columns["HiddenSort"].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Sorted += new EventHandler(dataGridView1_Sorted);
    }

    void dataGridView1_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            dr["HiddenSort"] = false;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataRow dr = dt.Rows.Add(2, "Testing", "Bilbo", "Baggins, Bilbo", "Bagshot Row #1", "Hobbiton", "SH", "00001", "555-2222", DateTime.Parse("9/9/2008"), 1, true);
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        if (dataGridView1.SortedColumn == null)
        {
            dv.Sort = "[HiddenSort] desc";
        }
        else
        {
            string sortname = dataGridView1.SortedColumn.Name;

            dv.Sort = "[HiddenSort] desc, [" + sortname + "] asc";
        }
    }

}
```

The trick here is adding a new column HiddenSort to the datatable that allows us to sort the datatable based on whether a row is new or not. That coupled with grabbing the sort column from the DataGridView allows up to keep the old sort order and maintain the position of new rows.

Comment: to make something invisible is not as efficient as deleting them, so tried to find solve it with deleting rows instead of making them invisible